# Help with a memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I made a class that uses NSURLConnection and KVC to make objects from plists on a server. Instruments says I have a bunch of memory leaks coming from the function that handles the data returned from the server:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    hasOutstandingCall = NO;
    NSError* sError;

    NSDictionary* tmpDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:receivedData 
        options:NSPropertyListImmutable
        format:NULL error:&sError];
    self.lastResponse = [ServerResponse new];
    //NSLog(@"server responded: %@",tmpDict);
    [lastResponse setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:tmpDict];
    if(tmpDict.count == 0){
        lastResponse.success = NO;
        lastResponse.errorId = -1;
        lastResponse.errorMessage = @"Couldn't understand server response";
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"serverDidRespond" object:self];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"requestDidFail" object:self];
        NSLog(@"failed to deserialize response");
        NSString* serverMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"SERVER SAID: %@",serverMessage);

        [serverMessage release];
        [receivedData release];
        return;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"serverDidRespond" object:self];

    if(lastResponse.success){
        if(lastResponse.resultQuery)
            NSLog(@"%@ response: query with %d rows",lastFName, lastResponse.resultQuery.count);
        else if(lastResponse.resultObject)
            NSLog(@"%@ response: object",lastFName);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"requestDidSucceed" object:self];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"%@ response: ERROR id: %d, message: %@",lastFName, lastResponse.errorId, lastResponse.errorMessage);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"requestDidFail" object:self];
    }

    [receivedData release];
}
```

Instruments says I am leaking a server response, and a bunch of other things that pass through this function. Does the "Responsable Frame" thing always refer to whatever originally created the leaked object no matter what? Should I just be looking for how this stuff gets leaked down the road or do I have a problem here in this function? From what I understand, tempDict, sError are autoreleased when they come back from serialization. I'm sending the supposedly leaked serverResponse into a synthesized setter that gets released in the dealloc method, so I don't see what the problem is. Anyone got some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.lastResponse = [ServerResponse new];
```

That is most likely a double retain, assuming that `lastResponse` is an `@property` declared as `retain` (or your setter retains).

When Instruments identifies a leak, it shows where the item was allocated, but that may not be the cause of the leak.  The leak will always be an unbalanced retain, but only sometimes will that retain be on the same line of the allocation (as it was in this case, apparently).

Comment: The property does retain. I don't see why that's a double retain though. What's the correct way to instantiate a retained property then? I thought that line was equivlanyt to: `lastResponse = [[[ServerResponse alloc] init] retian] ;`

Comment: `+new` is the same as `[[FooClass alloc] init]`;  it returns a `retained` object.   It is equivalent and, thus, if your property also `retain`s, it is a double retain.

Comment: So, either autorelease, or do it in 3 lines: init, pass to setter, release, right?

Comment: Yup; exactly.   Six of one, half a dozen the other.  The performance overhead of the autorelease pool is generally immeasurable.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I never picked that up until now. Thanks so much!